# Custom Keras/TensorFlow loss function penalising output change

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

My target is timeseries and I am looking for a cost function which would penalise the changes in the predictions, so for a batch size of *N* and model which has *k* outputs, in the loss function *y_pred* will be *N* x *k*

So I am looking for a way to do to introduce a penalty in the loss function like:

```
K.sum(K.abs(np.diff(y_pred)) * alpha)
```

Where *alpha* is custom input *1* x *k* cost per each change for each target. I am looking for a way of doing this kind of `np.diff` with the `Keras.backend`, is this possible? Or maybe there is a way of converting these tensors into `np.arrays`, do all my shenanigans and then back to tensors?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`y_pred[:,1:] - y_pred[:,:-1]`

it's `numpy` equivalent of `diff` with axis = 1 and is valid inside the loss function.